# Music feature extraction/Music Information retreival tools

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

I'm getting started with a project on using data mining and machine learning algorithms for music feature extraction and information retrieval. Can you suggest me some tools for the same _ firstly we are concentrating on feature extraction tools.I have found some like
 jAudioSymbolic extractor,Yaafe,openSmile..Can you tell me about some more tools and maybe any advice on going forward with a particular tool?

Comment: I worked exhaustively on MIR during my graduation days. You might want to check this https://github.com/abhinavsingh/music-information-retrieval . It mostly contains presentations and reports on work I covered (Feature Extraction, Supervised/Unsupervised Machine Learning), including resources to a lot of online tools.

Answer (score 1):

In my lab we use a lot of Vamp Plugins -- http://vamp-plugins.org/ -- for music feature extraction. (Full disclosure: my lab runs that website too.) They're C++ plugins which you can use from within lots of software, e.g. Audacity, [Sonic Visualiser](http://www.sonicvisualiser.org/), and from the command line.

The way I tend to get started is to extract the features from an audio file, then use [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) (pleasant machine-learning program) to try out some classification/clustering with the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Echonest. They provide value for many music features. You can see how to use echo nest in java in this tutorial http://preciselyconcise.com/apis_and_installations/echo_nest.php